# Have there been any cases of hypoxia-induced executions in the US or elsewhere in the world?

Tags: law, international, death-penalty

Have there been any cases of cerebral hypoxia-induced executions in US or elsewhere in the world? (IE using altitude or N2O for asphyxiation)

Since it is the most foolprooth and ethical method of execution, it was signed off and [approved by Oklahoma in 2015](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2015/apr/17/oklahoma-nitrogen-execution-method-death-penalty). If there have been no such executions, why is this the case? Why is this method not widespread and written into law?

Comment: Semi-serious side-note: [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euthanasia_Coaster) could be a fun alternative.

Comment: > it is arguably the most foolprooth and ethical method of execution if it is ***arguably*** the most fool proof and ethical method of execution, it cannot be the most fool proof and ethical method of execution; just as if it is ***politically*** correct, it cannot be correct.

Comment: "Cyanide poisoning is a form of histotoxic hypoxia" -- so yes, lots.

Comment: Thanks for the technicality @Roger, it is much appreciated. Do you have any other examples that do not involve chemical injections?

Comment: @Psi -- the classic 'gas chamber' execution method uses inhaled cyanide gas, not injection.

Comment: Good point @Roger, in that case I wonder why cyanide gas is chosen over N2O? Do you have any insights?

Wikipedia is not particularly informative on this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_chamber#Method_of_use

Comment: It looks like there has been modern developments on the subject: [In March 2018, Oklahoma Attorney General Mike Hunter and Corrections Director Joe M. Allbaugh announced a switch to nitrogen gas as the primary method of execution](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/post-nation/wp/2018/03/14/oklahoma-says-it-will-begin-using-nitrogen-for-all-executions-in-an-unprecedented-move/?noredirect=on).

Answer (score 1):

**Have there been any cases of cerebral hypoxia-induced executions in US or elsewhere in the world?**

The answer to that is in the very article you linked to:

> There are no reports of nitrogen gas ever being used to execute humans...

**If there have been no such executions, why is this the case?**

Again, answered in that same article (same paragraph):

> critics say that one concern is that the method is untested. Some states even ban its use to put animals to sleep.

Granted, there is a counterpoint:

> But supporters of Oklahoma’s plan argue that nitrogen-induced hypoxia – or a lack of oxygen in the blood – is a humane execution method. “The process is fast and painless,” said Christian, a former Oklahoma Highway Patrol trooper who wrote the bill. “It’s foolproof.”

I don't know Christian's credentials in regarded to human biology, but my guess is that the reason it's not in widespread use is simply because the 'foolproof' claim seems tenuous, at best, at this time given the fact that it's never been actually used on humans.

Comment: First point is invalid since the article is from 2015... 

Second point too since the method has now been fully tested on animals and is really fail-safe. It is also extremely well documented in research.

Comment: @ThomasHollis what does "really fail-safe" mean? As in approved by some authority for use on humans?

Comment: By fail-safe I mean it has 100% success rate as humans are truly incapable of survival without oxygen to the brain. Unlike most other execution methods that occasionally fail.

Comment: @ThomasHollis if it's been approved, then I guess I don't know why it's not more widespread...though if I had to guess, it's perhaps due to the general apathy towards the death penalty these days in general. Maybe it's just not a priority.

Comment: @ThomasHollis other methods occasionally fail because of practical or technical problems with implementation. Humans are truly incapable of survival after having their heads severed, yet beheadings sometimes fail. So it seems to me that not only the *idea* of suffocating people with nitrogen gas in order to kill them needs to be approved, but also specific protocols for killing them reliably using that method.

Comment: Filling a room with nitrogen gas or emptying a room of oxygen is clearly far more reliable than 3 seperate chemicals, electric chairs, axes, firing squads ... ect